# how to see what javascript is doing step by step when open a site?

Tags: javascript, debugging

When I open a site, I want to see all rendering process step by step as I press a kind of "Next Step" button.

At first page will be empty then every time I click Next browser will render next item and stop (DOM or whatever) and tell me which javascript line is executed, which css is applied and so on.

Is there a way to see all these?

Answer (score 3):

Tools like Firebug and Chrome Developer Tools allow you to [debug JavaScript functions](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/scripts.html) step by step. However, sounds like you'd like to walk through page rendering, which isn't related to JavaScript.

I don't know any tool which actually pauses rendering and lets you walk through it, but if what you're after is profiling you should check out Chrome's [Timline tab](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/timeline.html), which features detailed views and data about whatever happens on-page, including rendering.

Comment: yes that's exactly what I'm after. Pause rendering and let me see which object is going to be created, which line of js code is running at that time e.t.c . Timing Tab didn't help or maybe I just couldn't use it properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)([Chrome](http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/) and Firefox), Chrome Dev Tools (Chrome), [Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/) (Opera) or [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.ieinspector.com/dominspector/index.html) for IE.

Answer (score 1):

Use the excellent [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to debug through your javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Or use Chrome developer tools, it's nice too

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [Online JavaScript Tutor](http://jstutor.herokuapp.com/) for visualizing your code.

Comment: Perhaps the tutorial may be useful, but do you really think its an answer?

Comment: [Google Chrome Canary](http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html) is my browser of choice for development and to debug through JavaScript, but the [Online JavaScript Tutor](http://jstutor.herokuapp.com/) is great for beginners.

Comment: Online JavaScript Tutor seems to be offline, but the online [JavaScript Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/javascript.html#mode=edit) is a great alternative for beginners.